# Floating Action Button Background Blur

Tags: android

Floating Action Button Background Blur i've been looking for a solution for days
i am trying to make the background blurry when i click the floating action button but when i click the button it's not showing the options and the text is not showing when i run the program any suggestions?
here's my code

```
package com.example.chatdesign;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton;
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionMenu Plus;
    private FloatingActionButton findGroup;
    private FloatingActionButton startGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            FloatingActionButton findPeople = findViewById(R.id.FindPeople);
            findGroup = findViewById(R.id.findGroup);
            startGroup = findViewById(R.id.startGroup);
            Plus = findViewById(R.id.Plus);
            Plus.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                    if (opened) {
                        showToast("Menu is opened");
                    } else {
                        showToast("Menu is closed");
                    }

                }
            });

            findPeople.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick());
            findGroup.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick());
            startGroup.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick());

            Plus.setOnMenuButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Plus.isOpened()) {
                        Plus.close(true);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick() {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (view == startGroup) {
                        showToast("Button Add clicked");
                    }
                    else if(view == findGroup) {
                        showToast("Button Find Group clicked");
                    }
                    else {
                        showToast("Button Start Group clicked");
                    }
                    Plus.close(true);
                }

            };

        }

        private void showToast(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chatdesign.MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"
        android:text="@string/tap_to_start_a_chat"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold">

    </TextView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">
    </include>


    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@id/Plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:menu_fab_size="mini"
        app:menu_openDirection="down"
        app:menu_showShadow="true"
        app:menu_labels_textColor="@color/white"
        app:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/background_color"
        app:menu_labels_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        >


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/findPeople"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Find Users"

            />


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/findGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_group_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Find Group" />


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/startGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_group_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Start Group" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: i want to do something like this]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Kotlin file**

```
Blurry.with(this).radius(100).capture(ParentLL).into(mainBlurFL)
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ParentLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chatdesign.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"
        android:text="@string/tap_to_start_a_chat"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold">

    </TextView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"></include>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainBlurFL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@id/Plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
        app:menu_fab_size="mini"
        app:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/background_color"
        app:menu_labels_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        app:menu_labels_textColor="@color/white"
        app:menu_openDirection="down"
        app:menu_showShadow="true">


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/findPeople"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_label="Find Users"
            app:fab_size="mini"

            />


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/findGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_group_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_label="Find Group"
            app:fab_size="mini" />


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/startGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_group_24"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/Blue"
            app:fab_label="Start Group"
            app:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**More info :**

https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Comment: please add some more context as to how and why this solves the problem, perhaps describe the linked repo inline.

Comment: it will take screenshot of your container View and blur it with specific color. for more detail you can check the link:)